# Javascript strange date JSON representation on Safari

Tags: javascript, json, date, safari

I've found a strange problem with Safari (5.1.7 (6534.57.2)) where converting a date to a string I get a representation in which the number of milliseconds is negative.

```
new Date(1966,6,7,20,45,38,713)
```

the result of `.toJSON()` is:

```
"1966-07-07T18:45:38.-287Z"
```

Is it a Safari bug (as I hope) or is there any strange Javascript rule for which this is the expected (or even an acceptable) behavior?

Comment: I tried the following in safari: http://jsfiddle.net/6HYn9/ ...Seems like the milliseconds are stored correctly. I know in Chrome the output appends the timezone instead of the milliseconds, perhaps that's it?

Comment: Indeed the `getMilliseconds()` returns the correct value. It's the `toJSON` conversion that returns that strange value.

Comment: May I ask why you're using `.toJSON()` to turn the date into a string v.s. using `.toString()`?

Comment: what print in console new Date().getTimezoneOffset() and/or new Date(1966,6,7,20,45,38,713).getTimezoneOffset() ?

Comment: I believe what it's doing is saying "this many milliseconds left" vs "this many milliseconds have passed" (1000 - 287 = 713  vs 1000 - 713 = 287). Everyone always has to do it differently apparently. Giving milliseconds as a negative value of "what's left" seems to be used in other places as well.

Comment: @Chase: I'm not sure I understand why you are asking, but anyway I found the problem because of a failure of a test for a compiler that targets Javascript. The results of the tests are converted to JSON and compared to the expected results...

Comment: @Chase: for sure that date is before the epoch (so as an absolute number of milliseconds is negative) but -287 is wrong because to use such a representation the number of seconds should have been 39, not 38. BTW I don't think that this "number of milliseconds that is left" makes any sense (and it doesn't happen with dates after the epoch).

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing bug in the `toJSON` algorithm in the webkit bug tracker:

- [Date.prototype.toJSON does not execute steps 1-2](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105282)

It looks like another test case, but it may be the root cause of this issue as well.